# Joining a query from a separate database

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, outer-join

I have two Access 2007 databases, DB1 and DB2 for convention, and am trying to outer join the results of a query (Q1) in DB1 with a query (Q2) in DB2.

My code looks like this

```
SELECT 
  Q2.a, 
  Q2.b, 
  Q2.c, 
  Q1.d

FROM
  [Full name of Q1] IN 'C:\Users\...\DB1.accdb' AS Q1
    RIGHT JOIN
      [Full name of Q2] AS Q2
    ON Q2.a = Q1.a 
;
```

But returns the error "Syntax error in FROM clause."

I have tried this method with `LEFT JOIN`, as well as trying far too many brackets around things in fruitless attempts to get this to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have that directory in your query?

Comment: I have `'C:\Users\...\DB1.accdb'` to reference the second database that the query is not a part of. If you mean to ask why I have `" 'C:\Users\...\DB1.accdb' "`, it is because I shortened the full file path for the purpose of the question and saving space.

Comment: I didn't realize that you could directly reference the database path in your select query like that in MS Access. Quite honestly, I am not familiar with MS Access as much as I am with other databases.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that nifty little piece of information out a week or two ago. [Here's the Microsoft page (for office 2010+)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821148.aspx) which makes note of that functionality.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-to-use-access-2007-external-database-paths.3968620/

Comment: @HansUp, yes. The query is to be run from DB2.

Comment: @FutbolFan, I will try that fix, although the link I originally referenced doesn't explicitly state it I can successfully run the following query:  
`SELECT
  [Full Name of Query].a,
  [Full Name of Query].b,
  [Full Name of Query].c,
 FROM [Full Name of Query] IN 'C:\Users\...\DB.accdb'`

Comment: A side note about a deleted answer, obtaining the query by a subquery does work, and I failed to realize that was an option before. Good answer @FutbolFan

Comment: @Fritz Thanks for confirming that! I don't have a MS Access database here. So, I couldn't really test if that worked or not. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `[source Name] IN 'file path'` syntax is tricky.  If you want to alias `[source Name]`, you would need to include the alias between the `[source Name]` and `'file path'` pieces (instead of after `'file path'`).

But even that only works for a query which includes a single data source.  Once you join anything, the `[source Name] IN 'file path'` syntax breaks ... and is not fixable.  You need a different approach ...

```sql
SELECT 
    Q2.a, 
    Q2.b, 
    Q2.c, 
    Q1.d
FROM
    [C:\Users\...\DB1.accdb].[Full name of Q1] AS Q1
    RIGHT JOIN [Full name of Q2] AS Q2
    ON Q2.a = Q1.a;
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could rewrite your query something like this:

```
SELECT 
  Q2.a, 
  Q2.b, 
  Q2.c, 
  Q1.d
FROM (SELECT * FROM [Full name of Q1] 
IN 'C:\Users\...\DB1.accdb') Q1
RIGHT JOIN [Full name of Q2] AS Q2 ON Q1.ID = Q2.ID;
```